# Implement Java getter interface with setter in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a java interface:

```
    public interface TestInterface {
           String getName();
    }
```

I have a kotlin class:

```
class TestImpl(private var name: String = "name"): TestInterface {
    override fun getName(): String = name
}
```

But if I also want the setter method of the name field,

```
class TestImpl(private var name: String = "name"): TestInterface {
    override fun getName(): String = name
    // I don't want to write a setter like this
    fun setName(n: String) {
        this.name = n
    }
}
```

What better way can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Why don't you want a setter?

Comment: I think kotlin should have an easier way to implement a setter in this case. If both the getter and setter let me write it myself, wouldn't it be similar to java (translated by Google)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your point. If you mean that Kotlin should have an automated way to implement/provide getters/setters for fields, there are probably plugins for that but I don't know about Kotlin. In Java there is [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), which does exactly that. I don't think the "raw" language itself should have stuff like that. It's better to give the programmer full control, rather than providing such plug-in-like features. FYI: You should move the setter declaration to the interface as well. Or you should move the getter declaration to the impl-class.

Comment: For example: ```class Test1{
    var name: String = "name"
}``` , There is a default getter and setter for the `name` field, but in the case of the inherited interface I mentioned above, you cannot implement a setter by field by default. However, I can use lombok, but what if I want to use kotlin?

Comment: @akuzminykh 1. Kotlin does have "an automated way to implement/provide getters/setters for fields" (and so do C#, and Scala, and so on); the programmer still has full control for when it's useful. 2. It's perfectly reasonable to have only a getter in an interface, and a setter in a class implementing that interface.

Comment: @ForteScarlet Is it a must for the constructor param to `TestImpl` to be named as  `name`?

Comment: Also, the constructor param `name` is `private` in your code snippet `private var name`.Without changing the access modifier, it is not possible to set it from outside anyways without having an explicit setter defined.

Comment: Maybe not necessary. The answer below has solved this problem to some extent

Comment: It always feels ... whether I write a `setter` myself or via`@get: jvm`, my code amount has not decreased :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
class TestImpl(@get:JvmName("getName_") var name: String = "name"): TestInterface {
    override fun getName(): String = name
}
```

Then you access it as `x.name`/`x.name = ...` from Kotlin, and `x.getName()`/`x.setName(...)` from Java. Unfortunately, you also have `getName_()` in Java, but you don't have to use it.